# I have a code that shears the image but i would like it to rotate on the x and y axis with forward and backward mapping. Any advice on how to do this?

Tags: python, rotation, pycharm

I need the code to rotate the image instead of shearing using forward and backwards mapping.

I've tried changing the values of my variables, and changing the calculations, but can't make it work. Anything helps.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("lena.jpg", 0)
rows, cols = img.shape

x = 0.3
y = 0.2

def forMap (img, x, y):
rows = img.shape[0]
cols = img.shape[1]
imgForward = np.zeros((int(rows + cols*x), int(cols+rows*y)), 
dtype=np.ubyte)

for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        imgForward[int(row+col*x), int(col+row*y)] = img[row,col]
return imgForward

def backMap (img, x, y):
rows = img.shape[0]
cols = img.shape[1]
imgBackwards = np.zeros(shape=img.shape, dtype=np.ubyte);

for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        backCol = int (col-row*y)
        backRow = int (row-col*x)
        imgBackwards[backRow, backCol] = img[row,col]
return imgBackwards


aimg = forMap(img, x, y)
bimg = backMap(aimg, x, y)

cv2.imshow("Original image", img)
cv2.imshow("Forward mapping",aimg)
cv2.imshow("Backward mapping", bimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pick a center of rotation C and an angle of rotation theta.

Then define the complex number R = cos(theta) + i sin (theta).

The rotation function for each pixel P is:

M(P) = R * (P - C) + C

Where the product * involved is the complrx number's product. You can do the same with 2×2 rotation matrix R if you like.

So you just need to create two nested loops and for each pixel P find its rotated position using M(P).

You need to define what to do when the rotated position is out of the target image bounds. The simplest solution is to skip that pixel. The resulting rotated image will be cropped at the corners.

Other approach is of course define a new size for the target image using the rotated corners of the input image. For that you need to apply the function M to the corners and then find the max X, max Y, min X and min Y of the rotated corners.

C++ pseudo-code:

```
#include <complex>

struct Point
{
    double x, y;
    Point(double _x, double _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {};
};

// Rotate a point around a center using complex numbers.
// This is slow
Point transform(const Point& pt, double rot_angle, const Point& rot_center)
{
    auto R = std::complex<double>(cos(rot_angle), sin(rot_angle));
    auto C = std::complex<double>(rot_center.x, rot_center.y);
    auto P = std::complex<double>(pt.x, pt.y);

    auto M = R * (P - C) + C;

    return Point(M.real(), M.imag());
}


// Pseudocode for rotating the input_image.
// This code cropp the corners outside the bounds.
constexpr double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
auto center = Point(width/2, height/2);
auto angle = PI / 4.0:

for(int y = 0 ; y < height; ++y)
{
    for(int x = 0 ; x < width ; ++x)
    {
        auto point = transform(Point(x,y), angle, center);
        if(point.x < 0 || point.x >= width || point.y < 0 || point.y >= height)
            continue;
        auto color = input_image.get_pixel(x,y);
        output_image.set_pixel((int)point.x, (int)point.y, color);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mauricio any code you could provide to showcase this example would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @GustavJacobsen is that C++ code snippet clarifying things for you?